# Visual studio projects loads different references even if they target the same nuget

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have a C# solution in VS 15.7.4 with multiple .csproj.

5 of these projects reference the same nuget package

```
<package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
```

The problem I have is when I look at each project references properties they are not loaded from the same location and they do not have the same version number.

[image]

[image]

This is causing issue when I compile I get warnings that I should add binding redirect for that assembly. (I have this issue for multiple assemblies).

I validated on my end that in all the .csproj they have a hintpath that points to the packages folder version. This seems to be ignored in some projects.

1. How is it possible that the loaded references in one of my project is not the same as the other project when both target the same nuget packages?
2. How can I resolve this issue and make sure both projects load the same reference?

Comment: Does NuGet output the packages for both projects in the same path? I had similar issues in the past and i solved it by adding a NuGet configuration file to each project which states where to put the packages.

Comment: Yes all packages are stored in the same packages folder at the root of the solution.

Comment: Did you use nuget to add the references, or did you manually play with the files? Did the reference to that file already exist before the Nuget package was added? and do all of the relevant projects target the same version of the dot net framework? And trivial suggestion: have you tried closing all instances of Visual Studio, then removing the hidden solution project folder and re-opening the solution and rebuilding?

Comment: All nuget were added from the UI. All projects are .NET 4.6.2. I've tried closing and everything. Same behaviour is also reproducible on other coworkers computer.

Comment: You'd better report this issue to Microsoft via Help menu (there is a menu item down there).

Comment: Does your project implicitly introduce `.netstandard` assembly? Some packages (System.Buffers, System.Threading.Tasks.DataFlow, etc) have a netstandard2.0 build. When a netstandard2.0 assembly is referenced in the desktop project we automatically add all the assemblies needed to make it work: no more package references. To resolve this issue, please try to add binding redirect: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25773

Comment: Are the projects that make up the solution used by any other solutions?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT This seems to be exactly the problem I have right now. I was able to make the dll load from packages instead of Program files by using a settings in the csproj (something like dependsOnNetStandard). This resolved the issue (however I had add a manual reference to netstandard because some nuget packages were using it). 

Turns out it didn't fix my warning problem.

Comment: @Mathieu A, Version 4.1.2.0 was included in the VS setup packages, and it was included in the .NET 461 folder, but 4.1.1.0 was installed from the Nuget package. How did you install this nuget package? Do you install .NET 4.6.2 in your VS IDE? If possible, you could check all projects' .NET Framework version,   you could move the dll file 4.1.2.0, and then change the .NET version to be 4.6.2 for this project in property window, and then re-add the nuget package 4.1.0 version from the Manage Nuget Packages window.